How to fix notifications panel being hidden below the screen?
When I press on the clock in the top menu, the notifications panel appears hidden below the screen. Then I have to scroll it up for it to become visible.
How do I fix this so that the panel appears visible on top of the screen?
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/6biMv1DI3zs
